# swipe to delete not working on iPhone5, but works in simulator

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, iphone-5, swipe-gesture

I just made an simple app. The swipe-to-delete feature works fine in Simulator (iPhone5, iOS 7.0), but it's not working on iPhone5 device (iOS 7.0). When I swipe, it shows the delete button. But when I hit the delete button, nothing happens.
Here is my code:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject!, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        switch type {
        case .Insert:
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Update:
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            tableView.reloadData()
            }
            todos = controller.fetchedObjects as [Todo]
}
func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!) {
            tableView.endUpdates()
}

//RowAction: Delete
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject] {
    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title:"Delete", handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext {
            let todoDelete = self.fetchResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Todo
            managedObjectContext.deleteObject(todoDelete)
            var e: NSError?
            if managedObjectContext.save(&e) != true{
                println("delete error: \(e!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    })
    return [deleteAction]
}
```